# Vue not working in IE11 despite Babel Polyfill

Tags: vue.js, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, babel-polyfill

unfortunately, my most recent application is required to support Internet Explorer 11. This requirement came somewhat suprising to me, so I already built the applications frontend with Vue.js. The backend is written in Laravel, therefore I use laravel-mix/webpack.

This is my `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Obviously, IE11 doesn't support Vue.js so I tried the following ways of transpiling/polyfilling the code.

### 1. requiring polyfill

**Approach**: Adding `require("@babel/polyfill");` to the top of my `app.js` as described in https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

**Result**: Following Error Message shown in IE console:

> SCRIPT1003: ':' expected

Clearly a compatibility issue, since pre `data(){}` is invalid in ES < 5

### 2. using mix.babel

**Approach**: Adding `mix.babel(['resources/js/app.js'], 'resources/js/app.js')` to my `webpack.mix.js` as described in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix (I am using laravel 5.8.36). My `webpack.mix.js` now looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
mix.babel(['resources/js/app.js'], 'resources/js/app.js')
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Result**: Same Error Message as in **1**

### 3. using an mix extension

**Approach**: Installing this extension: https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill and configure my `webpack.mix.js` as described. My `webpack.mix.js` now looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-polyfill');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
mix.polyfill({
    enabled: true,
    useBuiltIns: "usage",
    targets: {"firefox": "50", "ie": "11"}
})
```

**Result**: Again, the same Error Message as in **1**

### 4. manually transpiling with babel-cli

**Approach**: Merely out of desperation I tried to manually transpile my `app.js` with the following command `./node_modules/.bin/babel ./public/js/app.js --out-dir ./public/js/`

**Result**: Stil no luck, same error as in **1**

I am really starting to get frustrated, so **any** help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Vue.js are you using? I have created a new Vue sample (based on [this link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)) and use the default preset (babel, eslint). it seems that it works well in IE browser. The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjJGi.png), please check it. Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Besides, here are some related articles about using babel with Vue.js, you could check them: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist, https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html, https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/babel.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get `Babel-Polyfill` to work, you could try using [Polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/), which automatically polyfills the selected Polyfills if the browser requires them.

All you need to do is go the [Create a polyfill bundle](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/) page, and select the polyfills you need. Then once you've made your bundle, copy the URL at the top and add a `<script>` tag with said URL to your `head`.

I personally haven't used it with Laravel, but I've previously fought with babel-polyfill myself, and ended up using Polyfill.io since i couldn't get babel-polyfill to work.

Comment: I created a bundle and included ES2015-2019 and included it by a <script> tag. The script gets loaded, but the error persists.

Comment: Did you remove all of the previous methods you tried? Could be they're conflicting. If you have done this, perhaps the polyfills aren't the issue.

Comment: yes, I every remain of previous methods whenever I tried a new one. I proceeded similarily with your suggestion.

Comment: Did you place the polyfill script as the first script in `<head>`?

Comment: Yes, I indeed did so

Comment: Hmm.. Not quite sure what the issue could be then. Sorry.